# What is the best method/tool to merge two .po translation files one old and one new with replace?

Tags: internationalization, translation, globalization, po, django-i18n

I want to merge two .po files together and produce new .po file. I am assume that many people will deliver different translation what need be merge into one.

First I want to replace all old translation in .po file with new one from other .po file and produce new merge file to use with batch or GUI. How to do it?

Second I want merge two .po files and decide manually in GUI which translation is the best if conflict and just add all new translation over empty translation. How to do it?

Please help with some solution since question is trivial but I spend many time to find suitable tool but without result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use translate toolkit [pomerge](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/translate-toolkit/en/latest/commands/pomerge.html)